# Django | Models where clause

Tags: django

How to construct a where clause using Django models:

```
insert in to tablename where email=emailaddress
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It is not clear what you want (at least not for me). Also your query does not make any sense at all because an `INSERT` statement has not `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are rather looking for a possibility to UPDATE an existing object.

```
obj=MyModel.objects.get(email=emailaddress)
obj.name = 'xxxx'
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

In case the email address is not unique, which is strange but let's suppose that, you should use the filter method and loop on result

```
users = MyObject.objects.filter(email=emailaddress)
for u in users:
    # your change here
    u.is_superuser = True
    u.save()
```